# I can not see python version in Mac terminal

Tags: python, terminal

I have installed python version 3.11.3 in macOS Ventura 13.3.1 , Python IDLE is showing in launchpad but in terminal it is showing python not found

I want to see my python version in terminal

Comment: Are you referring to `python --version` ? or to something else?

Comment: What you see in launchpad may be a dangling reference to something that no longer exists. Is Ventura an upgrade on top of an older OS installation, or a clean install on a new/wiped machine?

Comment: Is Python inside your $PATH?

Comment: How did you install Python?